# How to align textLabel in different corners of ImageView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, anchor

I am a novice in Swift.

Basically, I am trying to align the textLabel in different corners of the imageView based on the user input (TopRight, TopLeft, BottomRight, BottomLeft)... However, [as you can see here](https://streamable.com/e166rq), something really weird is happening when changing from one corner to another. Here is my code ( I am using a switch statement):

```
case .DownLeft:
        
        textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        textLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
case .DownRight:
        
        textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        textLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
case .UpLeft:
        
        textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        textLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        
case .UpRight:
        
        textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        textLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

It may due to the fact I need to **deactivate or remove constraints** that I do not need any more. So I have tried using one of the following functions to deactivate the constraints with no success so far

`.isActive = false`

`textLabel.removeFromSuperview()`

`textLabel.removeConstraints(textLabel.constraints)`

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It may due to the fact I need to deactivate or remove constraints that I do not need anymore

Absolutely right. You need to do more than just say `.isActive = true` when you create a constraint. You are creating the constraint *and throwing it away* every time. You need to *keep a reference* to every constraint that you activate, so that you can deactivate it later. It's called planning ahead!

Let's suppose you have an instance property `constraintsArray` which is an Array of NSLayoutConstraint. Then, for example, where you have:

```
textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
```

You would say:

```
self.constraintsArray.forEach { $0.isActive = false }
self.constraintsArray = []
let c1 = textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.leadingAnchor)
c1.isActive = true
self.constraintsArray.append(c1)
```

Using that sort of logic, the idea is that every time the case changes, you deactivate all the saved constraints, delete all the saved constraints, and then make the new constraints and add them to the list of saved constraints for next time.

Comment: Wow thanks. Neat explanation and it fixed the issues I have been struggling on myself for three days. As a newbie in Swift, I am definitely looking forward to get a copy of your latest book in the next following days..